# How to quickly add back missing file in xcode

Tags: xcode

I zipped up my project folder in xcode and moved it to a new computer. When I open up the project it has missing files (file appears red).

How can I add all these files back or re-link them. It is like 20+ files?

Why didnt xcode store the relative path?

Answer (score 8):

Xcode may not update location for some files of your project when you copy/move it from one environment to another. The easiest way I found is something like this:

1-Select your files like this, if they are in different groups, then repeat the flow on each group separately:

[image]

2- Show the file inspector:

[image]

3- You may notice Xcode has an absolute path for them, which is something not useful, so click on the little icon near `Multiple Values`. navigate to the folder where your selected files are stored in the finder and click "Choose".

Also, don't forget to change the `Location` to `Relative to Project`. Now you will get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

• Select all the missing files that are in one folder in Finder.

• Change *Location* to *Relative to Group* ( that's in the *File Inspector* View -> Utilities -> Show File Inspector )

• Click the *choose file* button; it is under the *Location* drop down menu; it is an image that looks like a very small window with a document inside it.

A *Choose folder containing the selected references* sheet should appear.

• find and select the folder containing the missing files in the finder, then click *Choose*

(Tested in In xCode v4.3.2)

Answer (score 1):

I normally keep all my files related to the project inside one folder (nested where necessary) and yeah I frequently exchange project files (zip and move) with my peers and nothing like that has ever happened to me.

Comment: all my files are in one folder.  it complains about missing .nib files which is located within the project folders

Answer (score 1):

You can always just drag the files en masse back onto the XCode window, and they'll get re-added. If you have file-system folders that match your Xcode internal organization that makes it even easier.

Answer (score 0):

The UI has changed. In Xcode 10, there's a tiny dot with an arrow in it next to the file path. This does **nothing** as far as I can tell.

There's an obscure folder icon offset up and to the right of that non-functional arrow... this actually is a button, and it DOES allow you to relink the file.

[image: Icon]

Comment: Can you provide a small screenshot of what you can see to be clearer?

Comment: For links in comments use `()` not `{}` btw :)