# Project Path incorrect

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I have received a project. The problem is the path for most of the project seems to be incorrect. I was curious how I would go about resolving this. I am using XCode 5.1.1.I am fairly new to Objective C and XCode so any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: you should provide more information regarding which error you receive, possibly with a screenshot. Additionally, upgrade xCode to the latest version.

Comment: I tried to add screen shot but stackoverflow won't allow it since my rep is < 10. And I did have xcode 6 but previous devs were using 5.1.1 so I downgraded for version control. As for additional details I'm getting Red text for sub groups as well as all the .proj files. The error is something to the effect of The file does not exist at the specified path. Is there a way to get around not being able to attach images on here?

Comment: Might be a link to some external site. Photobucket for instance.

Comment: That worked, thanks for that. http://i1368.photobucket.com/albums/ag174/W1lltheFlash/ScreenShot2014-10-24at94538PM_zps8f333baa.png

Comment: Try the steps in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14569669/1672895). That should solve your issue.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in response. I just tried this but for some reason when I attempt to open the file inspector nothing happens. Do you have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: unfortunately not. Let me know if I can be of further assistance.